# Linking to an Anchor on another page - help

Tags: links

Im trying the link to an anchor on another page which is possible with html but when I try in EE it is not working as it adds the last segment of my current page, like so:

Im linking from this page:

```
http://www.mysite.com/contact
```

The link from this page is:

```
http://www.mysite.com/#bottom
```

but the link gives this result

```
http://www.mysite.com/contact#bottom
```

It is adding the last segment of the current page??

Comment: What does the outputted html look like? It should be `<a href="/#bottom">`.

Comment: How do you mean, The actual link shows as: http://www.mysite.com/#bottom

Comment: Example code? Expect it's because you're not targeting root - <a href="/#bottom">...</a>

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see the anchor link you have at the moment but try this.

```
<a href="/#bottom">Your link here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If Chris Barber-Riley's syntax doesn't work you could also try:

```
<a href="{site_url}#bottom">Your link here</a>
```